# Emotion recognition in Google colab

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm currently working on a laptop with no GPU and my work is about deep learning. I want to try this repository in google colab: https://github.com/omar178/Emotion-recognition. The problem appears when I run it, the code displayed is this one:

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py:541: The name tf.placeholder is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.placeholder instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py:4432: The name tf.random_uniform is deprecated. Please use tf.random.uniform instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py:66: The name tf.get_default_graph is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py:190: The name tf.get_default_session is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.get_default_session instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py:197: The name tf.ConfigProto is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py:203: The name tf.Session is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.Session instead.

2020-03-21 13:13:28.283950: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
2020-03-21 13:13:28.287998: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:94] CPU Frequency: 2200000000 Hz
2020-03-21 13:13:28.288174: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x2e02d80 initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-03-21 13:13:28.288201: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
2020-03-21 13:13:28.290173: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcuda.so.1
2020-03-21 13:13:28.408807: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:983] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-03-21 13:13:28.409290: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x2e02f40 initialized for platform CUDA (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-03-21 13:13:28.409315: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Tesla P4, Compute Capability 6.1
2020-03-21 13:13:28.409472: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:983] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-03-21 13:13:28.409828: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1618] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: Tesla P4 major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.1135
pciBusID: 0000:00:04.0
2020-03-21 13:13:28.410110: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.0
2020-03-21 13:13:28.411925: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10.0
2020-03-21 13:13:28.413497: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10.0
2020-03-21 13:13:28.413968: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10.0
2020-03-21 13:13:28.415754: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.10.0
2020-03-21 13:13:28.416932: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.10.0
2020-03-21 13:13:28.419834: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7
2020-03-21 13:13:28.419923: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:983] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-03-21 13:13:28.420313: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:983] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-03-21 13:13:28.420647: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1746] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2020-03-21 13:13:28.420704: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.0
2020-03-21 13:13:28.421652: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1159] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2020-03-21 13:13:28.421678: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1165]      0 
2020-03-21 13:13:28.421688: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1178] 0:   N 
2020-03-21 13:13:28.421785: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:983] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-03-21 13:13:28.422166: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:983] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-03-21 13:13:28.422517: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_bfc_allocator.cc:39] Overriding allow_growth setting because the TF_FORCE_GPU_ALLOW_GROWTH environment variable is set. Original config value was 0.
2020-03-21 13:13:28.422555: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1304] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 7123 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: Tesla P4, pci bus id: 0000:00:04.0, compute capability: 6.1)
WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py:207: The name tf.global_variables is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.global_variables instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py:216: The name tf.is_variable_initialized is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.is_variable_initialized instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py:223: The name tf.variables_initializer is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.variables_initializer instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py:2041: The name tf.nn.fused_batch_norm is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.nn.fused_batch_norm instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py:148: The name tf.placeholder_with_default is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.placeholder_with_default instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py:4267: The name tf.nn.max_pool is deprecated. Please use tf.nn.max_pool2d instead.

: cannot connect to X server
```

I think the main problem is:

> cannot connect to X server

The script has to show my webcamera and a window of the emotion probability, and I think the problem is there.

Comment: Are you running a graphical interface using X11? Did you run this in the terminal without any GUI?

Comment: Are you using Colab? If yes, The code is running on their server (not your computer) which doesn't have a GUI like X server running. So the code might run on your personal laptop but it might not work on Colab without any modifications. Check this link out: https://ricardodeazambuja.com/deep_learning/2019/03/09/audio_and_video_google_colab/

Comment: I am using Google Colab. I tried the link you post it, but I am having the same problem. I reached out to start my own camera, but it has not still solve the problem.

Comment: Talking about graphical interface, I would say no, but I am not sure because I am beginner and it's not my code. The code just show two windows, one for probabilites of emotion and other to capture the video camera

Answer (score 0):

You need a x terminal emulator like x11 on mac/linux and xming on windows. I recommend downloading a terminal emulator for windows if you are on that. X server is x11 emulation to run certain graphical applications within your terminal or cmd/powershell console. I recommend creating a partition and installing linux for  development. (ubuntu or centos) Things set up once and works with no issues.